# Adding selected item from a drop down populated by javascript to a text box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

Hi I have a drop down whose items are populated by javascript and has no option tags. When the page loads, the drop down is loaded with all the options by an external JavaScript file. When the user selects an item from this drop down i would like this selected item to update a text box (which is on the same page) with their selection so I can then send this by email.

I can get it to work on a normal drop down with actual options tags that isn't populated by javascript, but can't get it to work with my Populated drop down. I have read on various posts that drop down items populated with JavaScript wont be read by the server because it is all done client side, and that a work around involves adding the populated drop down selection to a hidden field, but I cant find a method for doing so. I am also working with classic ASP to send the form

Hope someone can help,

Hi I forgot to mention that the drop down inst populated by inline JavaScript but rather from an external JS file

hi some  code i have used, works fine for a normal drop down, but not my one that is populated with JS

```
function ChooseContact(data) {

document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;

}


<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)"><option value='1'>1</option><option  value='2'>2</option></select>
```

Thanks R

HI - its all done using this external script 
    http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chainedmenu/index.htm

HI Here is a snippit of the exteranl JS file populating the drop down

```
/var hide_empty_list=true; //uncomment this line to hide empty selection lists
```

var disable_empty_list=true; //uncomment this line to disable empty selection lists

var onclickaction="alert" //set to "alert" or "goto". Former is for debugging purposes, to tell you the value of the final selected list that will be used as the destination URL. Set to "goto" when below configuration is all set up as desired.

var newwindow=0 //Open links in new window or not? 1=yes, 0=no.

/////DEFINE YOUR MENU LISTS and ITEMS below/////////////////

```
addListGroup("chainedmenu", "First-Select");

addOption("First-Select", "Select a course type", "", 1); //HEADER OPTION
addList("First-Select", "New Staff", "", "NewStaff");
addList("First-Select", "All Staff", "", "AllStaff");
addList("First-Select", "Learning, Teaching, Research and Knowledge Exchange", "",   "Learning");
```

addList("First-Select", "Leaders and Managers", "", "Leaders");

Comment: When the form is posted, the value of the dropdown should be sent, why do you need to pass it to a separate hidden/textbox?

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Comment: You sure can get info from the populated drop down list. As long as you're not using plain JS with IE.

Comment: How are you populating your dropdown. post that code also

Answer (score 0):

With your posted code, it should be perfectly possible to achieve what you are trying to do. I've constructed an example that expands on your code to show you how the input field can be updated.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/NHD4p/2/)

And also one that shows you it should still work if all of the options are generated via JavaScript. So maybe the issue you are having is elsewhere?

```
<select id="selecty" onchange="ChooseContact(this)"></select>
<input type="text" id="friendName" />

<script>
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = "One";
    opt.value = "1";
    document.getElementById("selecty").add(opt,null);

    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = "Two";
    opt.value = "2";
    document.getElementById("selecty").add(opt,null);

    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = "Three";
    opt.value = "3";
    document.getElementById("selecty").add(opt,null);

    function ChooseContact(data) {
        document.getElementById("friendName").value = data[data.selectedIndex].value;
    }
</script>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/NHD4p/9/)

Comment: But how is this done with a selected item in populated Drop Down?

Comment: It should work in exactly the same way, I've updated the jsFiddle with a dynamically added option to demonstrate this.

Comment: it just doesn't want to read the value with any JavaScript, the above doesnt work

Comment: Hi its still wont read the selected value Heres my Body onload event ehcih loads Drop Down items <body onload="initListGroup('chainedmenu', document.contactform.coursetype, document.contactform.course, document.contactform.coursedate, 'savestate')">

Comment: Hi Klors, thanks for your help. This works fine with actual <option> tags within the <select> tags, as you have done, But I don't have these as the drop down is populated by JavaScript

Comment: Please check my jsFiddle again, option 3 is an option created with javascript and still gets populated fine in the input when it is selected. It sounds like you may actually be having a different issue.

Comment: Unless this question is incorrectly labelled, and should be ASP.net, there is no viewstate available in Classic ASP.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Ted, I'll modify the answer to remove the viewstate explanation. The actual jsFiddle I posted for Rifki should still show that what he's trying to achieve is possible though.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get some points for all this work you've put in!